# How to test if an std::function<T> is constructible for template argument T

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, sfinae

I am currently writing a template class that takes a `Signature` template parameter and stores a std::function internally.

```
template <class Signature>
class Impl
{
    std::function<Signature> f;
};
```

This seems to work quite OK, except when the `Signature` template parameter is not valid, where the compiler fails with some template instantiation error in std::function.

Now because `Impl` clients  do not need to know the internals of `Impl`, it would be better to output some human readable message to the fellow developer that will use `Impl` stating that the `Signature` parameter is invalid.

Using a `is_invocable` trait class, something like :

```
static_assert(is_invocable<Signature>::value, "Template parameter Signature is invalid");
```

When attempting to write such a trait class, I've come up with this :

```
template <class Signature>
struct is_invocable : std::false_type
{};

template <class Signature>
struct is_invocable <std::function<Signature>> : std::true_type
{};
```

This does not seem to work however, because `is_invocable` does not want to check if `Signature` is std::function but rather if it is possible to construct a `std::function<T>` with `T` being the template parameter `Signature`.

How would it be possible to write a `is_invocable` class ?

Note: c++17 is not available.

Comment: Ahem.... http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function

Comment: @StoryTeller Ahem.... Types like std::function, lambdas, classes with overloaded operator() and pointers to functions don't count as function types.

What i'd want is closer to std::invocable but I can't use c++17

Comment: Amazingly enough, those (and others) are exactly the types you wanted to exclude from `Signature`. But if you don't bother reading the whole wiki page, there's nothing more for me to say.

Comment: @StoryTeller indeed I was wrong ever since I first looked at std::is_function before working on a solution, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [StoryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817643/storyteller) suggested in the comments, you want [`std::is_function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function) here, as the template parameter that you pass to `std::function` must be a *signature*.

```
template <class Signature>
struct Impl
{
    static_assert(std::is_function<Signature>::value, "");
    std::function<Signature> f;
};
```

`std::function` will check whether its *function object* is invocable with `Signature` for you.

Comment: `std::function` accepts 1/48th of the types your `static_assert` accepts.